ECPrivateKey to ECPublicKey without BouncyCastle
I'm trying to get the public key of EC from a private key.
I already do it using Python, Go which works fine, but I have not been able to do it in Java/Kotlin.
here is the python version:
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

private_key_b64 = "MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCAMM3sUprvk/VVF3vXhYcY0Vi9Ay1UPd4GLoBV/htAf2w=="

private_key_der = base64.b64decode(private_key_b64)

private_key = serialization.load_der_private_key(
    private_key_der,
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend()
)

public_key = private_key.public_key()

public_key_der = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

public_key_base64 = base64.b64encode(public_key_der).decode('utf-8')

print(public_key_base64)

here is the Go version:
    privKeyBase64 := "MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCAMM3sUprvk/VVF3vXhYcY0Vi9Ay1UPd4GLoBV/htAf2w=="

    privKeyDER, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(privKeyBase64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error decoding base64 private key: %v", err)
    }

    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(privKeyDER)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error parsing EC private key: %v", err)
    }

    k, ok := privateKey.(*ecdsa.PrivateKey)
    if !ok {
        panic("not ecdsa")
    }

    publicKeyDer, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(k.Public())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshaling public key to DER:", err)
        return
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("Public Key: %s\n", base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(publicKeyDer))

here is my Kotlin version:
    val privateKey64 = "MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCAMM3sUprvk/VVF3vXhYcY0Vi9Ay1UPd4GLoBV/htAf2w=="

    val decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKey64)
    val keySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey)
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
    val privateKey: PrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec)
    val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec)

    println("Private Key: ${privateKey.encoded.encodeBase64()}")
    println("Public Key: ${publicKey.encoded.encodeBase64()}")

but I have an exception:
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Only ECPublicKeySpec and X509EncodedKeySpec supported for EC public keys
how to do it without bouncycastle?

What Java and Kotlin version do you use?

@Robert I have tried 1.8, 11, 17 and 19 with sun.security.ec, also in android where the provider is conscrypt which have similar issue java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Must use ECPublicKeySpec or X509EncodedKeySpec; was java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec

During extraction, the raw public EC key must be determined from the raw private EC key. BouncyCastle exposes the class org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint, which supports the EC arithmetic with the corresponding methods (e.g. multiply()), so that the extraction is relatively simple, see e.g. here.

As far as I know, the JCA/JCE classes do not offer this convenience (see java.security.spec.ECPoint) or something similar, so that you have to implement this yourself, e.g. here (not tested) which is why the extraction is much more complex (with self-implementation, there is also the risk of security vulnerabilities and performance issues).

@Topaco thank you for the help, I end up using a version of https://github.com/Archerxy/ecdsa_java

I end up using a version of https://github.com/Archerxy/ecdsa_java code.
val curve = Ecdsa(Curve.SECP_256_R1)

val keystore = buildKeyStore {
    certificate("key") {
        hash = HashAlgorithm.SHA256
        sign = SignatureAlgorithm.ECDSA
        keySizeInBits = 256
        password = "changeit"
    }
}

val privateKey = keystore.getKey("key", "changeit".toCharArray()) as ECPrivateKey
val publicKeyReal = keystore.getCertificate("key").publicKey as ECPublicKey

// create public key from private
val publicKey = curve.privateKeyToPublicKey(privateKey)
println("Public Key Match: ${publicKey == publicKeyReal}")

and modified privateKeyToPublicKey to:
fun privateKeyToPublicKey(privateKey: ECPrivateKey): ECPublicKey {
    val priv = privateKey.s
    if (priv > N) throw RuntimeException("Invalid private key.")
    val p: Array<BigInteger> = fastMultiply(Gx, Gy, NUM[1], priv)
    val z: BigInteger = inv(p[2], P)
    val x = z.pow(2).multiply(p[0]).mod(P)
    val y = z.pow(3).multiply(p[1]).mod(P)
    val w = ECPoint(x, y)
    return KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
        .generatePublic(ECPublicKeySpec(w, privateKey.params)) as ECPublicKey
}

note it might include security vulnerabilities and performance issues

Just wondering, why do you prefer using a random GitHub project (last modified 3 years ago) over BouncyCastle, which is FIPS-certified?  Depending on your reason (e.g. on-disk size, performance), there may be a better alternative.

I just don't want to add other dependency in the code, I want to copy one class to my code and that's it. My goal is not to target FIPS certified crypto, it is a personal project and it run locally

@MatthewFlaschen just to be clear in my case if the correctness of the multiplication in the curve has an issue there is another logic to catch it, therefore I used the random project to do it. I just don't understand why conscrypt and JCE don't have this already.
I don't recommend anyone to use it if you don't understand what are you doing.

@hoxewe7277: Java crypto does have all that already, it's just not exposed as public. Behind almost every public class in the Java library is much more non-public code, in packages like sun.* etc. I would imagine an extensive vetting process must be undertaken to get any classes or methods into the public API. Rarely used functionality isn't going to made public.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk it is not a new API, it is already there keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec) but throw an exception even if they can get the public key from the private.
